# How to debug Alexa flash briefing skills? Not available error

Tags: aws-api-gateway, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-flash-briefing-skill

I am building a flash briefing skill for Alexa. I am using JSON, the JSON feed seems to be working well, went over the checklist and everything checks but when enabling the skill and starting my flash briefing I only get the "Custom Error Message" I have specified in the flash briefing skill definition, with no errors in the CloudWatch logs or anywhere else. No error when checking the feed elsewhere.

I am using AWS API gateway without authentication and the Content-Type is properly set to application/json and I double checked the response with JSONlint.

This is the URL for the feed:
https://l7kjk6dx49.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/postedmessage/feed

Following the suggestion of @Bob I updated the feed URL and enabled logging. The feed is called properly from my browser and there seems to be a call when trying to open the flash briefing and the response is OK, from Cloudwatch logs:

```
2016-11-19
16:15:34
Starting execution for request: 66ac03af-ae73-11e6-8719-1d2a8a213089
16:15:34
HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /postedmessage/feed
16:15:35
Successfully completed execution
16:15:35
Method completed with status: 200
```

Comment: I want to clarify where you are getting the "error message". Is it from API Gateway or your skills?

Comment: I get the error message from the Echo when I start the flash briefing and it gets to my skill. No error when checking the feed elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the Alexa skills API, but "Not available error" would seem to suggest that the URL is invalid or otherwise unavailable. Do you see any evidence of calls to your API in metrics or logs?

Comment: Yes. I just checked and seems to be getting called properly. I updated my question.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  Are you able to save the Feed URL in the flash briefing skill?  I keep trying to save the API gateway url and the skill keeps displaying "Error: There was an error parsing the feed. Please ensure that the feed is valid JSON or RSS." Have you seen this message?

Comment: @CalebGates Sorry, I have not played around with this for over a year.

Comment: @JosepValls at long last I figured it out.  My JSON wasn't 100% properly formatted.  Thanks for your reply.